# Building a "Task completion" workflow in Javascript

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I have an XML file that defines how a task must be completed.

Basically

Each tasks outputs (1) viewable data (2) params for the next task (3) or both viewable data and params

Right now, my thinking is that I'll take this XML, and literally generate JS code for it, that says (for the above example):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    task1();

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

   function task1() { ... task2(); task3(); }

</script>
```

PROBLEM: How would I do this if For example Task4 depends on both `Task2();` and `Task3();`

It seems like I need some sort of signal that says hey Task4 is ready to be called. Is there some eventing API in JavaScript I can rely on here?

Comment: `for the above example` !! Where is that example above?